# Change fonts in quarto pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

How to customize fonts in a quarto pdf document? I realized of the existence of `mainfont` and `fontfamily` options, but the documentation doesn't provide examples of how to use them and which fonts are available. Also, what are the fonts available for `monofont`?

Here is the documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#fonts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As said in the documentation, you can use system fonts (i.e. fonts installed in your system). So specify the font family of your system fonts as value of `mainfont` and/or `monofont` yaml key while using `xelatex` or `lualatex` as `pdf-engine`.

Now if you want to get the list of fonts installed in your system, you can use [`system_fonts()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/systemfonts/man/system_fonts.html) function from `{systemfonts}` package.

---

````
---
title: "Fonts in Quarto"
format: pdf
pdf-engine: xelatex
mainfont: Lato
monofont: Roboto
---


## Fonts

- mainfont: For LaTeX output, the main font
family for use with xelatex or lualatex. 
Takes the name of any system font. 

- monofont: For LaTeX output, the monospace 
font family for use with xelatex or lualatex:
take the name of any system font.


## Fonts available in system

```{r}
# install.packages("systemfonts")
systemfonts::system_fonts()
```
````

---

Also note that, if you use `fontfamily` to set the font-family, you need to use `pdflatex` as `pdf-engine`.

Comment: Is there a YAML options to change the font of the headers as well?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669656/10858321) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73689149/10858321) answers may be of help.