# How to override default titlefont in quarto?

Tags: pdf, yaml, latex, quarto

In my header I would like to specify a different font for the title like I did for the section and subsection headings, however when I try adding a title font I get the error

```
LaTeX3 Error: Command '\titlefont' already defined!
```

However, i'm not sure where the titlefont is already defined. I tried running it without the sansfont specification since I thought that it applied to all titles and headings, but I still got the same error.

```
format: 
  pdf: 
    mainfont: Calibri
    mainfontoptions: 
      - Color=154a39
    sansfont: Overpass-Light
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
            \newfontfamily\sectionfont[Color=ff7832]{Overpass-ExtraBold}
            \newfontfamily\subsectionfont[Color=ff7832]{Overpass-ExtraBold}
            \newfontfamily\titlefont[Color=154a39]{Overpass-Light}
            \addtokomafont{section}{\sectionfont}
            \addtokomafont{subsection}{\subsectionfont}
            \addtokomafont{title}{\titlefont}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669656/10858321), since there's already a defined command `\titlefont`, you can create a new command with an arbitrary name (for example I have used the name `\tfont` to change the title font).

```
---
title: "Changing Title font"
format: pdf
mainfont: "Libertinus Sans"
mainfontoptions: 
  - Color=154a39
include-in-header:
  text: |
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \newfontfamily\tfont[Color=Green]{Roboto Mono}
    \addtokomafont{title}{\tfont}
    \newfontfamily\sfont[Color=ff7832]{Comic Sans MS}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\sfont}
    
---

## Quarto

\lipsum[1]
```

---

[image: changing title font specifically]

---