# Set CMU Sans Serif font on pdf quarto

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation, quarto

I've been using Quarto for a few days to produce pdf documents. When specifying the main font used, I can perfectly well choose "Cambria" or "Calibri", but I cannot choose fonts like "Computer Modern Sans Serif".

```
    format:
     pdf:
     toc: true
     toc-title: "Text mining"
     number-sections: true
     colorlinks: true
     pdf-engine: lualatex
     mainfont: "Computer Modern"
     fontsize: 12pt
```

What changes should I make to the code to produce pdfs in the font of my choice? The solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603709/change-fonts-in-quarto-pdf-document) won't work.

Comment: Do you have the font Computer Modern Sans Serif installed on your system? If so, the approach you are trying should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`fontfamily`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html) in your yaml header with `pdflatex` engine and check [`The LaTeX Font Catalogue`](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html), which shows that Computer Modern Sans Serif is available. Here some reproducible code:

```
---
format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    toc-title: "Text mining et Première Guerre mondiale"
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
    pdf-engine: pdflatex
    fontfamily: "Computer Modern Sans Serif"
    fontsize: 12pt
---

This is some example text.
```